# Bios corrupted after cpu change

Tags: motherboard, bios, intel-core-i5, intel-core-i3

I have a Gigabyte GA-H77-M-D3H motherboard with an Intel i3 3240

Replaced the Intel i3 3240 with an Intel i5 3550

After the change the system loops during power on every 5 seconds and does not progress.  I attempted to clear the CMOS but this did not correct the problem.

Then attempted to revert to the Intel i3 3240 the system indicated the BIOS is corrupted and is reinstalled from the onboard BIOS backup.

Attempted to update the BIOS to F12 even though BIOS version F5 should support the 3550.

Ok works fine.

After attempting to upgrade to the Intel i5 3550 same result: restart loop and corrupted bios.

Could a damaged cpu cause the corrupted bios? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the motherboard actually supports that CPU? I doubt the cpu is bad. I just think its not supported and requires a bios update before using that cpu, given that there is a fix for this issue.

Comment: @LPChip It is on the official supported CPU list: [gigabyte.com/...](https://www.gigabyte.com/Ajax/SupportFunction/GetCpuList/?Value=4143&Type=Product)

Comment: What does the restart look like? Is there any indication the system completes POST at all? From your description I suspect you see no video or other indication at all and this is a bad CPU.

Comment: @Appleoditty: Yes indeed. Nothing more than coolers are running. And then a restart. Unfortunately the mainboard makes no beep even when it does the POST (and yes audio panel is connected to the new tower)

Comment: I just want to exclude a damage on the mainboard itself

Comment: "Could a damaged CPU cause the corrupted bios?" - The only time the BIOS was changed was when you performed the upgrade, and the upgrade was successful, the CPU made no changes to the BIOS.

Comment: @RamHound: Obvoiusly the bios get somehow corrupted when the i5-3550 was installed. After changing back to i3 3240 the bios again said it was corrupted and had to reinstall it

Comment: @Jorgbusch - A CPU cannot make changes to a BIOS, likewise, a BIOS can change the microcode of a CPU.

Comment: The BIOS isn’t getting corrupted. What you are seeing is the self recovery feature of the motherboard that resets the BIOS if it fails to POST a certain number of times. This saves you from hosing your system by putting in invalid values. The obvious question that hasn’t been asked is, is this a NEW cpu or used? Why do you think this CPU is any good? It sounds bad, and I’m 90% positive of it.

Answer (score 1):

In [theory](https://www.gigabyte.com/Ajax/SupportFunction/GetCpuList/?Value=4143&Type=Product),
your CPU is supported on this motherboard, and F12 is indeed the latest BIOS version.

But there may be other reasons that it cannot work with the motherboard or the RAM,
reasons having to do with fine-tuning voltage levels and more,
which will require a professional to set up.

Also, if the processor you’re upgrading to requires significantly more power than your current system uses, you might need to upgrade the Power Supply as well.
As far as I know, the I5 takes in at least 25% more watts, so you should check
if your PSU is already at full capacity.

It would take a professional to give exact directions, and you might need to call on one.

Comment: I tested it with a 350W and a 650W power supply and with 4 pin and 8 pin cpu power connector. The result was the same... also with two different fabricates of ram (both 1666MHz DDR3)

Comment: It might finally be that the documentation is wrong in listing this CPU model as compatible. A repair-shop might be able to better analyze the problem than we can from here.